# I have Aufenthaltstitel (German Residence Permit) and I am in India, can I visit Germany

Tags: germany, immigration, schengen, residence-cards

I have Aufenthaltstitel which is valid till next year. I was in Germany till october 2015, and then I returned back to India. I want to pursue employment opportunities in Germany, is it possible for me to visit Germany based on my current Residence Permit? Also how much is it easy/difficult to get Employment in Germany based on this Visa. Please help

Comment: Is your permit expired? If not, why can't you visit?